# Practical values for project discount rate

Tags: discount-rate

Are there any practical values for the discount rate I should use to value a project? Of course, the discount rate depends on the project itself, but are there any reference points what are typical discount rates used for e.g. high-risk projects? Is it  maybe 20-30% or less? I just need a reference point, but I couldn't find scientific literature that answers this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're UK-based, see the Treasury Green Book. Typically, it depends on the time-horizon. I think the discount rates is 3.5% up until 30 years, and maybe 4-5% thereafter.